# Behaviour of equinox service registry with service implementing two interfaces

Tags: osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle

I'm having a problem with service resolution of the equinox service registry implementation and I'm not sure whether this is a bug.

Here is a short description of my bundles and runtime:

## Bundle com.foo.api

- exports *com.foo.base* with an interface *IFooService*
- *IFooService* is not inherited from *ManagedService* or in any form related to it

## Bundle com.foo.impl

- imports *com.foo.base*
- imports *org.osgi.service.cm*
- registers *FooServiceImpl* which implements *IFooService* and also *ManagedService* from *org.osgi.service.cm*
- This it the component.xml of *FooServiceImpl*:

  ```
  <scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0"
   immediate="true" name="com.foo.impl.FooServiceImpl">

    <implementation class="com.foo.impl.FooServiceImpl"/>
      <service>
        <provide interface="com.foo.api.IFooService"/>
        <provide interface="org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService"/>
      </service>

     <property name="service.pid" value="fooservice"/>
  </scr:component>
  ```

## Bundle com.foo.user

- imports *com.foo.base*
- imports *org.osgi.service.cm*
- implements a component needing a *IFooService* (it does only  request this interface and not the *ManagedService* interface)
- The component.xml

  ```
  <scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" 
     name="com.foo.user.BarComponentImpl" 
     enabled="true" immediate="true">

     <implementation class="com.foo.user.BarComponentImpl" />

     <reference interface="com.foo.api.IFooService" 
       name="fooService" policy="static" cardinality="1..1" 
       bind="bindFooService" unbind="unbindFooService"/>
  </scr:component>
  ```

## Runtime

I'm using equinox, in config.ini the bundles described above, *org.eclipse.osgi.service* and *org.apache.felix.configadmin* are loaded.
(Beside others of course, but they are not of interest right now)

*org.eclipse.osgi.service* and *org.apache.felix.configadmin* both provide the package *org.osgi.service.cm*

- org.eclipse.osgi.servce provides version 1.4
- org.apache.felix.configadmin provider version 1.5

## The problem

Depending on the order of the bundles in config.ini it can happen that *com.foo.user* does not get a refence to *FooServiceImpl*.

Debugging into the equinox runtime I found that this happens:

- *com.foo.impl* uses *org.osgi.service.com* version 1.4 (from the *org.eclipse.osgi.service* bundle)
- *com.foo.user* uses *org.osgi.service.com* version 1.5 (from the *org.apache.felix.configadmin* bundle)
- The equinox registry detects that the interface *IFooService* is known by *com.foo.user* but the interface *ManagedService* which is also implemented by *IFooServiceImpl* is not compatible between *com.foo.impl* and *com.foo.user*.  The registry therefor does not return a service reference. Although the declarative services implementation lists the dependency as resolved using the `comp` command at the osgi console.

Is this the desired behaviour in this case? Shouldn't the framework return a reference to *FooServiceImpl* when requesting a *IFooService* even if the service implements another interface that is not compatible with the using bundle?

I didn't find any statement in the OSGi specification, but before opening a bug at eclipse I wanted to hear what the experts think.

## Update

Thanks to BJ Hargrave the main problem is solved (see below), but I'm still wondering why the framework handles these two cases differently

1. **Bundle A** requests *IFooService*, it imports only *com.foo.api*
2. **Bundle B** requests *IFooService*, it imports *com.foo.api* and *org.osgi.service.cm* (but in a "wrong version")

**Bundle A** gets a reference to the service, **Bundle B** doesn't.

Whats the difference between

1. "an interface is not known by a bundle" and
2. "an interface is imported in an incompatbile version"

when this interface isn't acutally used when requesting service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the framework return a reference to FooServiceImpl when requesting a IFooService even if the service implements another interface that is not compatible with the using bundle?

It is specified only to return services which are type compatible with the requester. You don't provide the specifics of how you register and find the service in question to provide a more definitive answer.

The solution here is to not install the `org.eclipse.osgi.service` bundle. A bundle such as that (a collection of unrelated, exported packages), causes these sorts of problems. `org.eclipse.osgi.service` is useful at compile time since you have access to a large palette of services. But at runtime, it creates the sort of problems you see. At runtime, it is better to have either the service implementation export the package, as Felix CM does, or have a bundle export just the service package to support the implementation and its clients.

OSGi provides a `osgi.cmpn.jar`, which is like `org.eclipse.osgi.service`, for use at compile-time. The latest versions of this jar include an unresolvable requirement to prevent people from using the jar as a bundle at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I see your point. Fixing the cause make absolutely more sense then working around the symptom.

Comment: Nevertheless I think _com.foo.user.BarComponentImpl_ should get a reference to the service since it only requests a _IFooService_ which is compatible with the implementation. Other interfaces the service may implement should be irrelevant. Or is there any reason for this I'm currently not aware of? 


For a better understanding I added the `component.xml` files to the description.

Comment: If you are using Declarative Services, why are you even messing around with ManagedService? Declarative Service will handle all your Configuration Admin interactions for you.

Comment: That's a good question ... blame on me ... obviously I missed that DS can handle this already. That solves my problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with BJ that it is probably the normal behaviour in OSGi. What you could try to solve the problem is to register the service separately for each interface. If that still does not help you could create a spearate class implementing ManagedService that forwards the config updates to the main service.